# While command in Python not working for me

Tags: python

I need some help with Python,
by the way I also looked it up and I could not fine the answer.
I was programing and using the while command and I wrote everything the right way on two commands:

1)

```
while l<10:                                                                                               
    y+=25                                                                                              
    transfer(x,y)                                                                                    
    w(5),b(10),w(5)                                                                                            
    l+=1
```

2. 

```
while h<20:                                                                                               
    y+=25                                                                                                  
    transfer(x,y)                                                                                          
    w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1)        
    y+=25                                                                                              
    transfer(x,y)
    b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1),b(1),w(1)        
    h+=1
```

so number one worked and number two is infinitely repeating...

so I checked all the code and it should work ok but it isn't sadly, please help me, and thank you in advance.

ps: I am a noob/beginner at python.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? I don't want to make an edit that might misrepresent your question

Comment: what is `transfer`? what are your intentions with statements like `w(5),b(10),w(5)`?

Comment: show the entire code, we don't know what "transfer", "b","w" does, or h default value

Comment: Does `transfer()` do anything with the variable `h`?

Comment: are the function w, b or transfer use the global variable h?

Comment: @SkanderHR Global variable is not an issue here. `h` is assigned to here (`h+=1`) so it is in the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a `print(h)` at the end of your loop so you can see where you went wrong.

Could it be your initial declaration of `h` not being an integer?

Comment: transfer is a def function I made

Comment: sorry I can't post the the rest of the code because it is too long and stackoverflow wont let me post it, sadly

Comment: transfer() has nothing to do "h"

Comment: w(5),b(10),w(5) is part of the turtle program I am making.

w=white
b=black

Answer (score 0):

THANKS GUYS I FUGURED IT OUT big thanks

I changed h<20 to h<10

because I have two lines of code runing when I used your print idea it pinted every two lines of turtle drawing so I halved "h" and it works!

THANKS GUYS!!!